# How to cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to complex type?

Tags: c#, json.net

Given the following c# code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public class BatteryStatus
        {
            // The battery level reports percentage of the full battery.The field can take values from 0 to 100% (0x00 – 0x64).
            // The value 0xFF indicates a battery low warning.
            public byte BatteryLevel { get; set; }

            public bool LowBatteryWarning { get; set; }

            public DateTime TimestampUtc { get; set; }

            public BatteryStatus(byte batteryLevel)
            {
                TimestampUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
                if (batteryLevel == 0xff)
                {
                    LowBatteryWarning = true;
                    batteryLevel = 0;
                }
                BatteryLevel = batteryLevel;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BatteryStatus batteryStatus = new BatteryStatus(40);
            string json = SaveObjectToJsonString(batteryStatus);
            Object obj = ReadObjectFromJsonString(json);
        }

        static string SaveObjectToJsonString(Object obj)
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
            return json;
        }

        static Object ReadObjectFromJsonString(string json)
        {
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            return obj;
        }

    }
}
```

Without changing the SaveObjectToString or ReadObjectFromString functions (and pretend that you didn't even see the source code for these), how can obj be converted to an object of the BatteryStatus class?

Attempting to cast directly like this:

`batteryStatus = (BatteryStatus)obj;`

result in the following error:

Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'BatteryStatus'.

Comment: You can't. You need to know what the data type of the JSON is in order to deserialize correctly. Sometimes this can be done with a special converter or using type IDs. If you knew in advance you could just do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BatteryStatus>(json)`

Comment: `var status = new BatteryStatus { BatteryLevel = obj["BatteryLevel"].Value<byte>()`, etc for the rest of the properties.

Comment: Of course, the `SaveObjectToJsonString` and `ReadObjectFromJsonString` should be changed to be generic, but you say "Without changing..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use JObject.ToObject method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BatteryStatus batteryStatus = new BatteryStatus(40);
            string json = SaveObjectToJsonString(batteryStatus);
            var obj = ReadObjectFromJsonString(json);
            JObject jObj = obj is JObject ? (JObject)obj : JObject.FromObject(obj);
            var deserializedBatteryStatus = jObj.ToObject<BatteryStatus>();
        }
```

Comment: I think we are almost there. The only catch is the your code relies on the fact that the Object returned from ReadObjectFromJson is in fact a JObject. That might now always be the case. What is the simplest way to serialize an Object into a JObject? I may need to do that to be 100% sure we have a JObject first.

Comment: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject always return JObject

Comment: This code also works, but seems a bit stupid: 
string json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
BatteryStatus batteryStatus2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BatteryStatus>(json2);

Comment: Yes, I know that JsonConvert.DeserializeObject always return JObject. But in my case the object returned from ReadObjectFromJsonString could in some cases not be a result of JsonConvert.DeserializeObject. So, you need to pretend that you don't know the inside of the ReadObjectFromJsonString function.

Comment: If you need serilize object to jobject you can use FromObject static method of JObject. `JObject jObj = JObject.FromObject(someObj)`

Comment: Could you edit your answer to reflect the previous comment?

Comment: I dont think it will be correct because _in some cases not be a result_ part not mentioned in question.

Comment: Not sure I understood your concern. I have edited my original question and added the fact that you should not base answers on knowing the source code for the functions.

Comment: Type conversion is  complicated topic. Depends on scenario also you  can use Automapper or TypeConverter magic.

Comment: The only think missing from the answer now is to add a null check after ReadObjectFromJsonString

Comment: In the cases where it doesn't return JObject, what *does* it return? Does it return an actual BatteryStatus instance? Does it return something that has a conversion operator to BatteryStatus, does it return a json string? The thing is, there is no way to write code to handle **all** contingencies. So if you want to have code that guarantees it will be able to extract a BatteryStatus out of *whatever*, then 1) that probably can't be done and 2) if it can, it'll be a lot of code. Please, be a little bit more specific in your question.

Comment: Yes, if it does not return a JObject it will return a BatteryStatus object. Either data behind it is populated from memory (by adding the real objects of type BatterStatus), or it could have been read from a json file into a JObject tree structure.

Comment: Just to clarify. The sample I included is a bit dumbed down to make it very self-contained and easy to test out. In reality the methods I typically call is named GetProperty and takes a propery name as parameter. It can return any kind of object, but the caller knows what type is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Would something using generics work for your use case?

We could change your ReadObjectFromJsonString and SaveObjectToJsonString to use generics...

```
static string SaveObjectToJsonString<T>(Object obj) where T: class
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
            return json;
        }

        static T ReadObjectFromJsonString<T>(string json) where T: class
        {
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
            return obj;
        }
```

Then the class can be specified when you call those functions -

```
BatteryStatus status = new BatteryStatus(40);
                string str = SaveObjectToJsonString<BatteryStatus>(status);
                BatteryStatus readBack = ReadObjectFromJsonString<BatteryStatus>(str);
```

Comment: No, the functions can't be changed to a generic version because the real scenario is more complex than in my example code. I read in an entire object tree from a json file in one operation and then I need to be able to cast a specific node in the object tree to a given type.  This works fine for simple types, but not for complex types like the BatteryStatus class.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
BatteryStatus BatteryStatus = ((JObject)obj).ToObject<BatteryStatus>();
```

Comment: Almost, but you need to pretend that you didn't see the implementation of ReadObjectFromJsonString. It may not always return a JObject.

Comment: @OlavT I am not admitting  that it returns JObject, it can return any object

Comment: No, If it doesn't return JObject the cast to JObject will cause an exception.

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution I ended up with by combining information from the other answers (use of JObject and generics):

1. Add a generic wrapper function around the original ReadObjectFromJsonString function:

```
    static T ReadObjectFromJsonString<T>(string json)
    {
        var obj = ReadObjectFromJsonString(json);
        if (obj == null)
            return default;
    
        JObject jObj = obj is JObject ? (JObject)obj : JObject.FromObject(obj);
        return jObj.ToObject<T>();
    }
```

2. Then the main code will become quite clean, simple and logical:

```csharp
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BatteryStatus batteryStatus = new BatteryStatus(40);
        string json = SaveObjectToJsonString(batteryStatus);
        batteryStatus = ReadObjectFromJsonString<BatteryStatus>(json);
    }
```